# PHP Can't use a hashed password in a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hash, passwords

I'm currently a 3th year web-dev student, and for a school project we have to build a website with a change password function using PDO and hashes, however I have run into a problem I cannot solve on my own, I also haven't found any similar questions on both google and stackoverflow.

we have to store 2 passwords in the database, the old password (which is the password the user has lastly used); and their current password (which will be used to login.)

all of the passwords are stored with a standard PHP hash (the password_hash() method)

When changing the user's password, I have to get the current password (the one used to login) from the database, and move it to the oldpassword (the last used password) column while putting the new hashed password into the database.

**the problem is:** I can't seem to use a hashed password in a PDO query, i do need to point out that I have never worked with PDO before, but after googling a bit I don't think I have an error in my query, but in the data being passed to that query.

this is where i get all the current data from the database

```
/*prepare and execute a query*/
$sqlStatement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password, oldpassword FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$sqlStatement->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement->execute();

/*Fetch the query results*/
$values = $sqlStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And this is where I try to store the data into the database using a PDO SQL query

```
/*Create variables to use in querys*/
$queryPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

/*Update the passwords*/
$sqlStatement2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE password, oldPassword VALUES (:password, :oldpassword)");
$sqlStatement2->bindParam(":password", $queryPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement2->bindParam(":oldpassword", $values["password"] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement2->execute();
```

$password and $username are variables passed from a form, to the function to change the user's password.

```
public function updateUserPasswords($username, $password){
```

What I find odd is: if i do a var_dump on $values["password"] I get the following data:
string(60) "$2y$10$BBCpJxgPa8K.iw9ZporxzuW2Lt478RPUV/JFvKRHKzJhIwGhd1tpa"

Where my query error gives me the following data:
$2y$10$

**it's as if only the hash is being sent to the query.**

**==EDIT==**

The SQL error being sent to the browser is:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('$2y$10$AC.aMG/gNV9zwGB/v/g7keW9jsZ80kuejrSh693DPuhOYChFxA6wu', '$2y$10$' at line 1' in /srv/jip/www/www.jip.nl/classes/user.class.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /srv/jip/www/www.jip.nl/classes/user.class.php(92): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /srv/jip/www/www.jip.nl/pages/first_login.php(26): User->updateUserPasswords('username', 'password') #2 {main} thrown in /srv/jip/www/www.jip.nl/classes/user.class.php on line 92
```

Comment: why are you using hashed string as input? you just need to pass the original password, and encrypt it on MYSQL side. Your var dump is also fine.

Comment: @noobie-php Can you please explain your comment? I couldn't see any problems in OP code regarding password politics.

Comment: you are updateing all tehe passwords in your table

Comment: What is your max length on your password field in the database? I'm guessing it's 7

Comment: @noobie-php Why would you use MySQL hashing functions? PHP has much more secure hashing functions available than MySQL does (for instance `password_hash()` uses bcrypt with multiple rounds).

Comment: @Farkie the maximum length is 250

Comment: May be i was unable to explain my self what i meant is, you dont need to have hashed password passed as input.

Comment: @noobie-php the password is retrieved from the server, and is thus hashed.

Comment: @noobie-php then what should be passed as input when dealing with passwords? The literal string? I think not.

Comment: @noobie-php unless something has radically changed with MYSQL that allows it to generated salted and hashed passwords rather than just hashed strings, you really do.

Comment: User inputs password in form > form is sent > PHP hashes input from form > PHP stores hash in database. Everything's fine here.

Comment: @AlanMachado: this is the issue `User inputs password in form > form is sent > PHP hashes input from form` this part is not happening, other then this , logically its ok

Comment: What is that "query error" you are talking about?

Comment: @AlanMachado: Refer to Mark's Answer that was my point

Comment: @noobie-php I'm sorry but mark's answer states a completely different point from yours. He's talking about rehashing the parameter while comparing it, you were talking about using MySQL engine to hash it.

Comment: @AlanMachado: i wont comment after this, i already cleared my point , regarding what i was trying to say, you can see in follow up comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Edited the question to include the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't retrieve the data using the hashed password, because [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) generates a new hash with a different salt whenever it's used

Retrieve the record using just the username, then use [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to validate the password

**EDIT**

Your update query references columns, but no table, and without a WHERE clause:

```
$sqlStatement2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=:password, oldPassword=:oldpassword WHERE username = :username");
$sqlStatement2->bindParam(":password", $queryPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement2->bindParam(":oldpassword", $values["password"] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement2->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStatement2->execute();
```

binding with the appropriate values

Comment: allright, thanks for your quick response, i'll give it a try and check back when I have done so.

Comment: Well explained and quite logical

Comment: the where clause is indeed missing, haven't added it yet because the table only has a single result for testing at the moment..

As for the table, it's included in the **$this->db**

Answer (score 1):

Turned out my query was indeed incorrect, it's been a while since i last made an update query and I put it in the same format as an insert query.

Mark Baker's solution also fixed the problem with retrieving the old password from the database. retrieving the information using just the username has worked.